# Как сверстать блоки с float:?

Tags: html, css

Для блока `<div class="dataRow">` автоматически вычисляется высота `height: 0px;` (в этом блоке лежат 3 `div` с `float:left;`).

Требуется, чтобы высота блока была правильно определена по содержимому.

```css
/*стиль для блока даты*/

.dataRow {
  display: block;
}
/*стиль для блока из стрелок и поля ввода*/

.counter {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
}
/*стиль для поля ввода*/

.tablo {
  cursor: default;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
/*стили для стрелок*/

.activeBut {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: default;
  color: #7f7f7f;
}
.activeBut:hover {
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
.activeBut:active,
.activeBut:focus {
  color: #000000;
}
/*стиль для таблици даты*/

.dataCalendar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dataRow">
    <div class="counter" onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
      <div class="activeBut">&#9650;</div>
      <input type="text" class="tablo" value="01">
      <div class="activeBut">&#9660;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="counter" onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
      <div class="activeBut">&#9650;</div>
      <input type="text" class="tablo" value="01">
      <div class="activeBut">&#9660;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="counter" style="width: 40px;" onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
      <div class="activeBut" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">&#9650;</div>
      <input type="text" class="tablo" style="width: 36px;" value="2001">
      <div class="activeBut" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">&#9660;</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table class="dataCalendar">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Январь</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Пн</td>
        <td>Вт</td>
        <td>Ср</td>
        <td>Чт</td>
        <td>Пт</td>
        <td>Сб</td>
        <td>Вс</td>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать

```
.dataRow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
/*стиль для блока даты*/
.dataRow
{
  display:block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*стиль для блока из стрелок и поля ввода*/
.counter
{
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
}
/*стиль для поля ввода*/
.tablo
{
  cursor: default;
  width: 16px;
  text-align:center;
}
/*стили для стрелок*/
.activeBut
{
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: default;
  color: #7f7f7f;
}
.activeBut:hover
{
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
.activeBut:active,
.activeBut:focus
{
  color: #000000;
}
/*стиль для таблици даты*/
.dataCalendar
{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
      </head>
 <body>
  <div class="dataRow">
   <div class="counter" onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
    <div class="activeBut">&#9650;</div>
    <input type="text" class="tablo" value="01">
    <div class="activeBut">&#9660;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="counter" onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
    <div class="activeBut">&#9650;</div>
    <input type="text" class="tablo" value="01">
    <div class="activeBut">&#9660;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="counter" style="width: 40px;" onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
    <div class="activeBut" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">&#9650;</div>
    <input type="text" class="tablo" style="width: 36px;" value="2001">
    <div class="activeBut" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">&#9660;</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  

  <table class="dataCalendar">
   <thead>
     <tr><td colspan="7">Январь</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Пн</td><td>Вт</td><td>Ср</td><td>Чт</td><td>Пт</td><td>Сб</td><td>Вс</td></tr>
   <tbody>
  </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте clearfix для очистки флоатов.

Можно так:

```
 .dataRow:after,
 .dataRow:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
 }
 .dataRow:after {
    clear: both;
 }
```

Можно через класс

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}


Для Ie8 

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: В варианте Elena Semenchenko меньше кода. И похоже, что этот метод будет работать почти везде .[overflow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

Comment: Нет не меньше. И вариант этот устаревший и не правильный, почитайте про свойство overflow hidden для чего оно нужно, явно не для очистки флоатов, это старый костыль который уже давно не используют. Создайте один раз класс .clearfix и используйте его потом в разметке, либо юзайте stylus и nib() там функция clerfix() уже есть по умолчанию.